# Z-index not working with multiple absolute positioned elements

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have a fairly simple interactive map with a bunch of "pins", which upon hovering over display a corresponding "tag".

CSS (irrelevant properties omitted):

```
#map { position: relative; }
.map-pin { display: block; position: absolute; }
.map-tag { float: left; left: 20px; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; }
.map-pin:hover .map-tag { opacity: 1; pointer-events: all; }
```

HTML (only included one pin div for obvious reasons):

```
<div id="map">

    <div id="map-pin-1" class="map-pin">
        <div class="map-tag"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The issue is that the tags, despite giving them any sufficiently high z-index value, will not appear above all the other pins. It seems that they will only appear above the pins which are above the specific tag in the DOM. For example, `#map-pin-3 .map-tag` will appear above `#map-pin-1` and `#map-pin-2`, but `#map-pin-4` will appear above the tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I realized that the reason the others pins appear above the tag is because the height and width of the .map-pin div is set to 20px. This was done to prevent the large div from preventing the other pins from being hovered over. I inserted an anchor directly inside `.map-pin` as a sibling of `.map-tag` and set that to 20x20 (and `.map-pin` to auto), so the tag appears when the `.map-pin a` is hovered, rather than the whole div. If I increase the div size, it covers the other pins but prevents hovering them. If I decrease it, it allows pin hovering, but the pins appear above the div.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see any z-index defined on the map-tag element in your code sample. Second it appears you have an issue with stacking context. Take a look at the [css spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) and read carefully because z-index, IMO, is overly complicated.

Also one thing that helps me when working with z-index is the "Inspect element" option in Firefox. If you select an element to inspect you will see in the lower right corner a "3-D" option. Click that and you can visualize the stack order better.

Comment: There is no z-index in the CSS because I didn't think I would need it. I then experimented with various values by inspecting the elements in Chrome. That's why I mentioned in my description that the issue persisted "despite giving them any sufficiently high z-index value". Can you explain why setting the z-index of the tags to one hundred, or even a billion, wouldn't make them appear above everything else on the page?